# showing a div after selecting a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code and what I need to with this is when selecting one radio button I want to display subscription_rate div. At the moment both main DIVs display together. I need to keeping hide subcription_rate div when click on a radio button.

hope someone help me out this..

this is my code so far...

```
<div class="form-element-row">
    <div class="first-child">
        <label for="name">Registration Period<img alt="required" src="images/required_star.png" />:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="last-child">
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="1" />1 Year
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="2" />2 Years
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="3" />3 Year                              
    </div>
</div>

<div class="subscription_rate">
    <div class="first-child">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div class="last-child">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Subscription Rate</th>
            <th>1 Year</th>
            <th>2 Years</th>
            <th>3 Years</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;">Lanka Institute Rates for Tutors within their subscription period.</td>
            <td width="18%">Rs.3000</td>
            <td width="18%">Rs.4500<br /><span>Save 25%</span></td>
            <td width="18%">Rs.7500<br /><span>Save 50%</span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `change` event handler with radio button and use `show()` / `hide()` functions.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4vpBx/1/)

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide();
$('[name=period]').change(function(){
    $('.subscription_rate').show();
});
```

To toogle between change of radion buttons, you can use [toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vpBx/3/)**

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide();
$('[name=period]').change(function(){
  $('.subscription_rate').toggle();    
});
```

Comment: I need to hide subscription_rate div again clicking on selected radio button... can I know is it possible?

Comment: can I use slideDown() inside toggle() to add some animation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23132/discussion-between-tharanga-nuwan-and-adil)

Comment: Adil I have a problem with toggle()

Comment: I think your deviating from your OP, it would be better if you put new question

Answer (score 1):

First hide the div in the css:

`display:none;`

then use this script:

```
$('input[name="period"]').change(function(){
  $('.subscription_rate').slideDown('slow'); // .slideDown(800);
});
```

Comment: can you tell me how I use slideDown() with slow speed.. I tried something like .slideDown({default: 800}); but Its not working..

Answer (score 1):

First hide it by using `.hide()` in jquery and use `.show()` when you want to display it after the user clicks the radio button,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
     $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if($('input[type=radio]:checked').val()==1){ //check which radio button is clicked, here its 1
            $('.subscription_rate').hide();
        }else if($('input[type=radio]:checked').val()==2){
            $('.subscription_rate').fadeIn("slow"); // show the div with fadeIn
        }else if($('input[type=radio]:checked').val()==3){
            $('.subscription_rate').hide();
        }else{
            $('.subscription_rate').hide(); // if in any case radio button is not checked by user hide the div
            }
    });
});
```

[JSFIddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swarne27/SqzU9/)

Comment: can I add fadein fade out effect to this when it show and hide?

Comment: Yes of course you can instead of .show() use .fadeIn("slow"); or whatever. I've added it to jsfiddle in the answer

Comment: I need to hide it when I click the radio button which already checked one? is it possible?

Comment: you can hide or show whatever the way you want, but in your question you have said you want to display the div which is initially hided

Comment: what do you want to do? do u want to hide the div when you click the radio button with period value 1 and when you click the radio button with period value 2 you want to display it?